# api key doesn't display in my account wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, api-key

I'm building a new self-hosted wordpress website and would like to install the stats plugins. 
I need to get the API key but when I go to Edit My Profile the API key is not here. 
Then I tried from the Dashboard > Users > All Users > Admin .. still no API key.

- All I have is
- Personal Options
- Name
- Contact info
- About yourself
- And then the button "Update Profile"

My self-hosted website is here : http://kimchistory.co.cc/

Screenshot here : 
http://i45.tinypic.com/e1alw9.png

[image]

If someone knows how to get the API key please let me know!

Comment: Self-hosted WordPress sites don't have an API key out of the box. What "stats plugin" are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-hosted WordPress sites don't have an API key. The plugin is asking for your WordPress.com API key.

More info here: http://en.wordpress.com/api-keys/

> #### How do I get one?
>
> For Akismet users: You can [get an API key here](http://akismet.com/get/).
>
> For all other services: When you [sign up for a WordPress.com account](http://wordpress.com/signup/) we will email you an API key. If you already have a WordPress.com account, your API key is listed on your profile page, which you can get to by clicking the “My Account” link in the top left when you’re logged in.
>
> #### Where will my API key be?
>
> It will be in your welcome email. To make sure you get the email, avoid free services like Hotmail and MSN and check your spam filter if it doesn’t show up in a few minutes. (Also, consider whitelisting *@wordpress.com.)